# List parameter not provided for web part connection

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, connection, list-webpart

I'm new in SP and my goal is to have one list, several qChartViews will show list's data and one DateFilter web part to select date range for all charts.
I created a list and defined the list parameter via SPD 2013 according to [How to compare two date's in 'Date Filter' webparts?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85494/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-date-filter-webparts).

```
<ParameterBinding Name="StartDate" Location="None" DefaultValue=""/>
<ParameterBinding Name="EndDate" Location="None" DefaultValue=""/>
```

But in step 9, when I want to add it to Date Filter web part, parameters added in List (StartDate, EndDate) are missing in connection list, see picture. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

I have several qChartView web parts and they're visible in connection list, but the list parameters aren't.

Thanks fro any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the list that you add the parameters in the connections list.

[image]

And get the parameters in the connection field name.

[image]